# How can I get Experience Manager Session Preview temporary files to be tidied up?

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, configuration, session-preview

Experience Manager Session Preview causes temporary files to be created for pages and binaries in my staging website (html pages published to Tomcat 7 - stuff like `index_789816da-1614-403f-9538-879fd05b9c57.html`). Some of these are more than two days old - how do these get cleaned up? I checked all the web app config files, but can't find any settings there, or by searching the online docs.

UPDATE: There are some messages in the cd_preview log:

> DEBUG JPAPublicationMappingDAO - Retrieving PublicationMapping by mappingKey: ae553687-ecbd-4645-955b-6b7998c6d45d. 2013-11-21 10:15:03,401
>
> DEBUG JPAItemDAO - Removing binary meta from storage 2013-11-21 10:15:03,405
>
> ERROR SessionWrapperFactory - Exception while cleaning-up session data: Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction

Comment: I would think they get deleted automatically, but perhaps the file system permissions prevent it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a hotfix for that... (this is fixed in SP1).

If you're on SQL Server (I think with Oracle it is exactly the same fix), run this on the preview database:

```sql
IGNORE THIS, SEE UPDATE 2
```

**UPDATE**

Now that I think of it... run this on all your Content Delivery Databases...

**UPDATE 2**

Fixed with cumulative hotfix CD_2013.0.0.86156

Comment: Thanks Nuno - any idea of the official hotfix number (I cannot find it on sdltridionworld.com), so I can request it from CS and this can be "officially" applied - the databases are off limits for us CMS devs.

Comment: Hotfix only contains jars and no SQL. Its for:
- TT84562 Undo transport package contains only one binary with VariantId
- TT84847 Hanging threads in broker
- TT85023 Error in Precommit phase if we deploy CustomMeta to FileSystem and one of the values is empty
- TT85248 Wrong title of embedded binary in the ITEMS table after undo
- TT85262 When we store page content on a filesystem we always capture it with UTF-8 chartset during undo capturing
- TT86037 When attempting to deploy content, it fails with error: Unable to persist data entity, org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

Comment: I am going to try it out anyway, as its got some other useful fixes in... will update shortly if it works or not

Comment: Yes, the SQL change was not needed, just another way of getting the same results...

Comment: Yes - the hotfix mentioned indeed fixes the problem