# Experience Manager temporary files not cleaned-up

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1

I have XPM configured and can see temporary files being created on the filesystem and also session items being created in the session preview DB. After some time, the items get cleaned up from the DB table(s), but the sessionpreview-files remain on the filesystem. I have already checked question [How can I get Experience Manager Session Preview temporary files to be tidied up?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3660/how-can-i-get-experience-manager-session-preview-temporary-files-to-be-tidied-up), but no luck there.

My questions are:
1. which process/service should clean up the temporary previewsession-files on the filesystem? As I see it, the web.xml contains a SessionManagementContextListener that gets invoked on session expiration, and should remove the file(s)?
2. any ideas about the probable cause of this issue?

Comment: Are your files located inside the document root of the web application? Could it be a permission problem?

Comment: Hi Quirijn, the files are outside the document root, and so I added a filter to set the claim store WebClaims.REQUEST_ROOT_PATH in order to make path resolution work. See my previous post about this issue https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/9641/why-are-the-filenames-of-xpm-temporary-files-truncated

Comment: Are you setting the real_path, root_path and other claims as described in that post? Also, what does your cd_core log have to say?